# Closed meta questions tell me I don't have enough rep

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just noticed that at the bottom of closed questions here on meta.programmers.stackexchange.com, it tells me:

> You must have at least 5 reputation on Programmers to answer a question.

I have over 1000 rep, so that's not an accurate message. (And I am offered the Your Answer box on open questions.) It doesn't do that when I look at closed questions on programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me and 2 others have reported this a while ago on Meta.SO. Its been reproduced on at least SuperUser and Gaming. Currently its `[status-planned]`, but who knows when it will actually get fixed

Root question: [Misleading error message on SE metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65390/you-must-have-at-least-5-reputation-on-parent-site-to-answer-a-question-for-c)

Other reports

- [Per-site metas say I need more than 5 reputation to answer a closed question…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66528/per-site-metas-say-i-need-more-than-5-reputation-to-answer-a-closed-question)
- [“You must have at least 5 reputation on [parent site] to answer a question” for closed questions (despite having the rep)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64767/misleading-error-message-on-se-metas)

Answer (score 1):

This has been reported over on Meta Stack Overflow - but I don't have the link right now.